# How can i create my own UI in WIX set Up

Tags: wix, customization

I want to create a set up of my .Net windows application using WIX. Though WIX provide some built in UI but i am not able to create my own UI in WIX.
Is there anyone who can help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own managed bootstrapper application using WPF. Please take a look at [this article](http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/) for a very basic example. [This post](http://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/) contains some additional details. You can also download a source code of Wix itself and inspect its installer project.